# Would unexpected power loss while disk encryption harm my HDD?

Tags: encryption, filevault, macos

My external HDD was being encrypted using macOS' disk encryption feature.

The job would take several days because the size of HDD is 8TB, so I let it alone turned on.

When approximately 24% done, entire electricity of my house was cut out.

The encryption job was on its progress so I'm worrying about physical error of HDD and a data corruption.

File system is HFS+, and journaling is on.

Should I reformat HDD and start from the scratch? If physical error is highly possible, should I dump the HDD and buy a new one?

Comment: HDDs these days have protections against heads damaging the platters upon power-loss. If that does happen, it won't matter whether you were writing encrypted data or not. You need a suitable bad block checker (a S.M.A.R.T tool or an equivalent of e2fsprogs) for your OS.

Dumping the HDD would be an extreme situation - especially if you aren't considering years of wear and tear and the HDD is nearly end-of-life anyway. 8TB HDDs may not be "that" old. :)

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, **physically, there is no difference from encrypted to non-encrypted accidental powerdown.** If a HDD powers down while in use, it can get the same amount of damage if what it writes at that point is encrypted or nor. It makes absolutely no difference for the HDD.

In the case of the actual data, here things can be different. A sudden power-down can result in data being encrypted incorrectly, resulting in possible additional CRC inconsistency.

In your case, modern encryption systems can just resume from where they were stopped manually or accidentally, so you should be fine resuming the process.

Comment: I use my HDD of old PC as external USB storage and many times its USB cable gets disconnected from the port while running, probably due to faulty wire. Till now I didn't see any physical damage to HDD so I'm sure accidental power off cause no harm to the HDD. Just the data which is being read/written may get interrupted.

Comment: It's the USB connectors at fault, not the cable itself. The small USB connector is just a bad design. Some Seagate models still have serious issues when disconnected while in use.

Comment: My HDD is seagate and 7yrs old. No noticeable issue has been seen till now on accidental power cut. I'm sure it's a myth that it damages your HDD. It doesn't.

Comment: I got a pretty big stack of them saying otherwise. Most are 320GB and 1.5TB models.